# maven-assembly-plugin: jars without version only

Tags: maven, version, maven-assembly-plugin

I need to create a distribution of my app with all of (my own) jars without version numbers.

I managed to configure the the assembly descriptor to add the jars without version numbers but it also adds the same jars *with* version numbers:

```
<assembly >
  <id>distribution</id>
  <formats>
    <format>jar</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <moduleSets>
    <moduleSet>
      <useAllReactorProjects>true</useAllReactorProjects>
      <binaries>
        <outputFileNameMapping>${artifact.artifactId}.${artifact.extension}</outputFileNameMapping>
        <outputDirectory>.</outputDirectory>
        <unpack>false</unpack>
      </binaries>
    </moduleSet>
  </moduleSets>
</assembly>
```

The output contains:

```
META-INF
DependingOnJarWithoutVersionNumber.jar
DependingOnJarWithoutVersionNumber-10.11.123.jar
JarWithoutVersionNumber.jar
JarWithoutVersionNumber-10.11.123.jar
```

> How do I prevent adding the jars *with* version number while keeping those *without* version number?

---

The final goal it to apply the version number removal only for own jars (with known `groupId`s.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare the name of the target JAR file with the `destName` property:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
    <id>zip</id>
    <includeBaseDirectory>true</includeBaseDirectory>

    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <files>
        <file>
            <source> ${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar</source>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <destName>${project.artifactId}.jar</destName>
        </file>
    </files>
</assembly>
```

Also see https://medium.com/@kasunpdh/using-the-maven-assembly-plugin-to-build-a-zip-distribution-5cbca2a3b052